# While converting X509CertificateHolder object into X509certificate am getting following exception

Tags: android

Subject Public Key Info:

```
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Unable to load Public Key
494676423688:error:0f00007b:elliptic curve routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNKNOWN_GROUP:external/boringssl/src/crypto/ec_extra/ec_asn1.c:345:
494676423688:error:06000066:public key routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECODE_ERROR:external/boringssl/src/crypto/evp/p_ec_asn1.c:100:
494676423688:error:0b00007d:X.509 certificate routines:OPENSSL_internal:PUBLIC_KEY_DECODE_ERROR:external/boringssl/src/crypto/x509/x_pubkey.c:158:
```

this error is occurred in only Q cookie after removing setprovider("BC")
from below code:

```
 X509Certificate  x509object= new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC")
                                .getCertificate(x509certificateHolder);

cert = (X509CertificateHolder)certIt.next();
 signerX509Certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
                                .getCertificate(cert)
```

Comment: Used spongy castle provider its working fine.